# How to prevent shared modules from duplicating in lazy loaded modules in Angular/Webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

So lets have following modules

1. AppModule - main module generated by CLI
2. SharedModule
3. MaterialModule
4. CustomModuleA - Lazy loaded
5. CustomModuleB - Lazy loaded

Now, `SharedModule` and `MaterialModule` is loaded with main `AppModule`. Both are used in `CustomModules`. Bundles for those lazy modules contains `SharedModule` and `MaterialModule` despite the fact that those 2 are loded on app bootstrap.

Is there a way to let "compiler know" that given dependency will be provided and there is no need for including it in given bundle? (like `provided` scope in `Maven`)

Comment: Hey @Antoniossss, did you find any answer for this?

Comment: If I recal correctly I have ditched the subject as it was not critical, but I dont think I have solved that. Maybe newest webpack solves that out of the box?